# Mapping Europe with tmap package

Tags: r, raster, tmap

I would like to map some raster data using tmap package. My geographical extent is Europe and R cannot find the map of Europe altough I got the latest version of R and all packages required. I am trying this:

```
 library(tmap)
 data(Europe)
 tm_shape(Europe) + tm_fill()
```

And it writes this

```
 Error in as.list.environment(environment()) : object 'Europe' not found
```

I found this way to do it on almost every website, havent a clue why it doesnt work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The Europe dataset has been dropped from `{tmap}` since release 2. But it used to live there, and you can still find it in many older blogposts and even SO answers (including mine I am afraid).

You might get it to work if you downgrade {tmap} to version 1.11-2 or lower.

Or you might build Europe shape from other packages, there are a plenty. For a quick & dirty visualization you may consider `{rnaturalearth}`, for something more fancy consider `{giscoR}`, which is interfaced to Eurostat.

```
world <- rnaturalearth::countries110
europe <- world[world$region_un=="Europe"&world$name!='Russia',]

library(tmap)

tm_shape(europe) + tm_fill()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find a combo that works. This is just a sample of subsets.

```
library(tmap)

tm_shape(countries_spdf[countries_spdf@data$subregion == "Western Europe", ]) +
tm_borders()

tm_shape(countries_spdf[countries_spdf@data$subregion == "Eastern Europe", ]) +
tm_borders()

tm_shape(countries_spdf[countries_spdf@data$region == "Europe", ]) +
tm_borders()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [giscoR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/giscoR/index.html) pacage and, for the boundaries, I pass to t`m_shape()` function the output of the   `gisco_get_nuts()` function from the giscoR package.

Usually, I define and save in a geojson file the map's BBOX by selecting my area of interest visually using the  https://geojson.io tool

A code template may be the following

```
library(sf)
library(geojsonsf)
library(giscoR)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)

map.bbox <- st_bbox(geojson_sf(geojson = "_data/bbox_europa_continental.geojson"))
country.ISO3_CODE <- gisco_countrycode %>% filter(continent == "Europe") %>% select(ISO3_CODE) %>% unlist(use.names = F)

gisco_get_nuts(country = country.ISO3_CODE, 
               spatialtype = "RG", nuts_level = 0) %>% 
  tm_shape(bbox = map.bbox) + tm_polygons() + tm_borders()
```

[image]

Notes: to date it seems that the giscoR package miss Bosnia and Kosovo boundaries